# How to remove laravel-permission from any action of a control?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-permission

In laravel 8/fortify app I use spatie/laravel-permission and in control I have several actions(including ajax requests) with same rules :

```
public function index()
{
    if ( ! Auth::user()->hasAnyPermission([PERMISSION_ADMIN, PERMISSION_USER_WITH_ACCESS])) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login')
        ->with('status', 'You have no permission to enter Items.index methods');
    }
    ...
    return view('admin.item.index', [
        ...
    ]);

}
```

It works, but I wonder if there is a way to short it someway?

Think about using construct, like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if ( ! Auth::user()->hasAnyPermission([PERMISSION_APP_ADMIN, PERMISSION_APP_MANAGER])) {
         Auth::logout();
         return redirect('/login')
             ->with('status', 'You have no permission to enter Items pages');
    }
}
```

But not sure if that is good way ? As far as I remember in 5.x such way did not work...
Which way can be used now?

Comment: You can define middleware on routes. so no need to write in every controller's constructor OR to check in every method. more details - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware

Comment: Can you post the code for ```hasAnyPermission``` method

Comment: hasAnyPermission is method of spatie/laravel-permission